# hook_form_FORM_ID_alter function in Drupal

Tags: forms, drupal

I would like to overwrite a form by creating a custom module. But therefor, I need to get a hold to my form ID in the function.

Drupal.org mentionned the `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)` function, but when I apply this to my form, it doesn't respond. Do I have a syntax error when I use following statement?:

```
function redactie_omgeving_fiche_node_form__form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    echo(var_dump('ONZE redactie_omgeving__fiche_node_form__form_alter'));
}
```

and this is my form:

```
<form class="node-form node-fiche-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/node/1/edit" method="post" id="fiche-node-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nice little trick to make sure you have the right form id is to first use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to get the form id, *then* use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7).  For example, use:

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_set_message($form_id);
}
```

to see a Drupal message of all form id's on the current page.  Once you have the correct id, then place it into `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.  Try that and make sure you are using the right form id.

Comment: Great trick! Do I need to replace the `hook_form` by the naming of my own module?

Comment: So in other words `function hook_form_fiche_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 echo 'ok!';
}` should work?

Comment: Yes, but replace "hook" with the name of your module not "hook_form".  So `function MODULENAME_form_fiche_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { echo 'ok!'; }`

Comment: You are my hero!! Thank a million!